# ASP.net MVC4 Clear Model Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile

So I have a simple action in my controller.  The project is a MVC Mobile Application.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}
```

this gives an form to enter data.  I then handle the data in the post back.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ScanViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Scan ns = new Scan();
        ns.Location = model.Location;
        ns.Quantity = model.Quantity;
        ns.ScanCode = model.ScanCode;
        ns.Scanner = User.Identity.Name;
        ns.ScanTime = DateTime.Now;

        _db.Scans.Add(ns);
        _db.SaveChanges();

    }

    return View(model);
}
```

I want to clear the fields in the form and allow users to enter data again.  However I get the exact same values back into my inputs.  How can I clear them in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `this.ModelState.Clear()`

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the [**PRG**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

Just redirect to the Action method which is meant for the `Create` Screen. You can use the `RedirectToAction` method to do so.

[`RedirectToAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a **GET** request to the specified action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ScanViewModel model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       //Code for save here
       //..............
       _db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index","User");
   }
   return View(model);
}
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

Assuming your controller name is `UserController`.

Comment: A note on this - if you want to carry a message you will need to use TempData rather than ViewBag as it's a new request.