# Passing empty model back to create view after successful add - textboxes still contain data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

ASP.NET MVC 4 web app, SQL Server 2012, Entity Framework 5.

I have a view, based on scaffolding - after successfully creating a record in the database rather than calling

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

I want users to be able to immediately add another record. However if I instead return an empty model - eg like this:

```
return View(new Tag());
```

The textboxes still have the old model data in. Shouldn't they be cleared?

What I want to do is clear all textboxes so the user can enter the next item.

Comment: I just had a thought - perhaps this is the browser autocomplete storing the values?!

Comment: I've now confirmed it's not browser autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:
[ASP.net MVC4 Clear Model Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046698/asp-net-mvc4-clear-model-values)

You need to call the Http Get Action on the Create Action Method - like this:

return RedirectToAction("Create", "ControllerName");

This appears to reset the model, using the PRG pattern. Still not totally sure why it didn't work the first time but this makes sense as a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in `ModelState`. It contains values that was posted and fill them on client. You can clear it with `ModelState.Clear()` if i remember this. But it is not so good solution. Good solution redirect to right action instead of returning `View(new Tag())`

Comment: ModelState.Clear didn't work - I guess what you're alluding to is my answer below?

Comment: this does not clear the url, so if you are doing something with url, use RedirectToAction("Create", "ControllerName");